# Virtual MacOS setup for react-native development

Tags: windows, reactjs, macos, react-native, virtual

I'm trying to setup a virtual MacOS machine to test my react-native application on apple systems. The issue I am running into comes after I try to run commands like 'react-native init projectName'. I always get a strange set of errors, EIO (i/o) most of the time. Sometimes the same command gets through, but fails somewhere in the midst of running. I have also tried to set up my project form the Windows host machine, where the same command in bash runs perfectly fine. I can then test it on Android Simulator. However, when I try to run it with the XCode Simulator on the MacOS virtual machine, it fails to build (possibly because of the same input / output errors). I am doing this through a shared folder called 'VMware Shared Folders', where I map a folder from my host machine to the guest.

Any ideas where this problem might be coming from? Maybe you guys could provide me with other ways of sharing the same folders?

```
VMware Workstation 14;
Windows 10 Host;
MacOS 10.13.5;
Freshly installed react-native and required prerequisites.
```

[I've also attached a sample terminal screenshot for clarification on the types of errors I receive.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8Tyq.png)

Comment: EIO means error while doing Input/output operation. In your case its mkdir. Can you try creating project in document directory or somewhere else (not shared location)

Comment: I forgot to add that I can successfully run react-native init on any other folder in the MacOS system. However, my goal is to setup a shared folder, so I could develop on Windows and just open the virtual machine to test it out on apple systems.

Comment: I had same requirement a year back. I also though of same, but there are many chances of error(like yours). So I managed to get things working my pushing my code in github, and then whenever I want to test in other environment, I just pull and build